# How to properly finish a python MPI script?

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py

I'm writing python code using mpi4py and its not finishing unless I manually cancel the job. My code is something like this:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
if __name__ == "__main__":
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size()
    rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()
    if (rank == 0):
        print("MPI WORLD SIZE: ", size)
        res = fun()
        # print out results
        print(res)
        MPI.Finalize()
        exit(0)
    else :
        fun_worker(rank)
```

The results are printed but the script doesn't finish its execution.

Comment: What happens if you delete `MPI.Finalize()`?

Comment: `MPI_Finalize()` and `MPI_Init()` are implicitly called by `mpi4py` unless specified otherwise.

Comment: @mkrieger1 nothing seems to change

Comment: Cannot repro, works fine with 2 workers for me